# Create a new namespace on request in Firestore Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to implement a peace of functionality in my lib for work with Firestore Datastore in Google Cloud.

However, I could not find any documentation - only for AppEngine:
[Implementing Multitenancy Using Namespaces](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/multitenancy/multitenancy)

It would be great if anyone helps with such request or share he is own code for that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass in the namespace to any keys you create or queries you run.

Notice that the constructor for [KeyFactory](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/KeyFactory.html) can take a namespace parameter.  Similar for [EntityQuery.Builder](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/EntityQuery.Builder.html).